# Calling method from view in model on model instance, rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sanitize

I have a sanitize method in my model from the rgrove sanitize gem

```
Micropost
  belongs_to :user

  def sanitized_gif_url
    self.gif_url = Sanitize.fragment(micropost.gif_url, elements etc to sanitize here).html_safe
  end
```

I want to call `sanitized_gif_url` in my microposts view but when I do with this code I get `undefined local variable or method sanitized_gif_url' for #<#<Class:0xb886cf0>`

I only really understand instance/class methods very vaguely but I know I want to call my method on my instance of micropost in my view. I thought I was already doing that when I call `self.gif_url` referring to the original object in the db then run my method on the instance.

**EDIT: `gif_url` is the attribute I want to sanitize.

View code

_micropost.html.erb

```
....  
<%= sanitized_gif_url %> (I know this doesnt look right)
....
```

Comment: Could you please add the code you have in the view?

Comment: Added. Its very simple, i am getting the error on that line :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without passing a method explicitly to an object, it is passed to `self`, which in a view means a view instance. So you need to pass your method to a Micropost instance instead (e.g. `@micropost.sanitized_gif_url`). Its method definition also has some errors too:

```
##Micropost.rb
##micropost in micropost.gif_url is undefined. you can use self.gif_url or just gif_url, as self is implied. 
##I'd remove "self.gif_url =" too unless this is used in a callback to sanitize url before saving
  def sanitized_gif_url
    self.gif_url = Sanitize.fragment(gif_url, elements etc to sanitize here).html_safe
  end
```

However, if the purpose of this is to show a sanitized method in views, I'd suggest you create a view helper instead of a method for Micropost.

```
##helpers/application_helper.rb
def sanitized_gif_url(url)
  Sanitize.fragment(url, elements etc to sanitize here).html_safe
end

## _micropost.html.erb
<%= sanitized_gif_url(@micropost.gif_url) %>
```

The advantage of this is separation of the concerns for the model and view. You've also eliminated the dependence of `#sanitized_gif_url` on the particular implementation of Micropost. So you can use this method for any other urls or models with urls what you want to sanitize.

Comment: This seems to all make sense, I will mark this as correct. I went with the first example as I already figured it out but the second seems nice as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You have written your `sanitized_gif_url` as an instance method meaning that it must be called on an instance of the `Micropost` class.

The controller for the view you are speaking of should set the set the `Micropost` instance as an instance variable for the view to access. Something like `@micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])` (get the specific instance of `Micropost` you are working with in the view)

Then in the view modify what you have in this way:
`<%= @micropost.sanitized_gif_url %>`

An instance method is called on one instance of the class. A class method is called on the class itself.

Comment: Thankyou, I needed a bit of help on this one when I started trying to understand to many things.